# What is the Java equivalent of .NET's Enterprise Library?

Tags: java, configuration, data-access, logging

I am a .NET guy but recently have been placed on a Java project. Is there a java equivalent of .NET's Enterprise Library? More specifically, I only need a configuration manager, data access helper (parametrization and sanitize), and maybe a logger.

What are the hot tools for java development?

Comment: Might want to accept some answers... 34% of 49 questions is kinda low

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the sort of horizontal tools that the likes of [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) provides. These have been around for years, in some cases remaining useful today (e.g. [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/), [Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/)), in other case now outdated and superseded by better things ([Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) by [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), [Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) by [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/)).

For simplified data access, the likes of [iBatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/) or [Spring JDBC](http://www.springsource.org/about) are good starting points.

Comment: Almost everyone uses Apache Commons on top of Java standard edition.

Comment: @Dean J: I think its usage may be decreasing, partly due to the outdated examples mentioned, and also because the language itself has caught up a fair bit.

Comment: hah, what they call "enterprise" in .NET, in Java is called "commons" :)

Answer (score 0):

Logging: [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j) (or the [logging built into Java](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html))

Configuration and data access helpers: [Spring](http://www.springsource.com/developer/spring) and perhaps [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/).

Comment: log4j and especially JUL aren't good compared to Logback or slf4j.

Comment: @Lord.Quackstar log4j is completely sufficient ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the .NET Enterprise Library is just a collection of libraries. For your particular needs there are many options. I'll suggest one of each:

- data access - [Spring's DAOs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/dao.html) (not separate from spring); the [generic-dao](http://code.google.com/p/generic-dao/) project (I haven't used it though)
- logger - [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/), [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)
- configuration manager - [commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/)

Answer (score 0):

For DAO, I use [Easier Java Persistence](http://www.easierjava.com/), which is extremely light and requires 0 configuration. Its really worth it